# make a non-routing link in asp.net MVC 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm trying to include a link in my MVC 3 project to a file in the App_Data folder, but the MVC always wants to make the link <controller>/<view>/App_Data/file.  Unfortunately App_Data is not the lowest folder in my web server, so I can't use just /App_Data/...

Is the trick to muck with the routing table?

Answer (score 0):

Read the file in app_data into temp memory using system.io methods, clear the response buffer from a new action in a controller, (ensure the controller returns void). The once read in, write the file directly to the output stream of the response object. Remember to set the content type on the response object to help the client machine read/understand the file.

Hope this helps.

Chris.

Comment: Interesting, but not what I had in mind.  I just want to have a link on my page that points to the file in App_Data.